# How to use LimitOffSetPagination instead of PageNumberPagination in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have written a code in Python using Django Rest Framework to fetch data from database(MySql) and view it in browser using Pagination(`LimitOffSetPagination`).But It is not working fine.But when I used `PageNumberPagination` it was working great. so I am posting my new code.Commented parts of my code is actually for `PageNumberPagination`. So just ignore it. Please tell me the necessary changes needed and help me out. The error coming is:

> Exception Value:   index() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'request'

view.py

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination


@api_view(['GET','POST'])

def index(self, request):

  if request.method=='GET':

    all_dataobj=fetchdata.objects.all()

    page = self.paginate_queryset(all_dataobj)

     if page is not None:

      pserializer = self.get_fetchdataSerializers(page, many=True)

      return self.get_paginated_response(pserializer.data)

    pserializer = self.get_fetchdataSerializers(all_dataobj, many=True)

    return Response(pserializer.data)

    # paginator = StandardResultsSetPagination()
    # result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(all_dataobj, request)
    # pserializer=fetchdataSerializers(result_page,many=True)
    # return paginator.get_paginated_response(pserializer.data) 


 elif request.method=='POST':

  serializer=fetchdataSerializers(data=request.data)

  if serializer.is_valid():

    serializer.save()

  return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

      'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 
      'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
      'PAGE_SIZE': 10
      }
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', m.index, name='index'),
]
```

I am even posting the pagination.py file which I was using earlier for PageNumberPagination. Please do suggest me if there is any necessary changes needed to be done or I should remove the file as a whole itself????

pagination.py

```
from rest_framework import pagination

class StandardResultsSetPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
page_size = 10
page_query_param = 'page'
page_size_query_param = 'per_page'
max_page_size = 1000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I solved this problem myself...so felt like posting the solution...It may come in help to someone...so I am posting the view.py, pagination.py and settings.py files...

view.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .pagination import CustomPagination


@api_view(['GET','POST'])

def index(request):

  if request.method=='GET':

    all_dataobj=fetchdata.objects.all()

    paginator = CustomPagination()
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(all_dataobj, request)

    pserializer=fetchdataSerializers(result_page,many=True)

    return paginator.get_paginated_response(pserializer.data) 


  elif request.method=='POST':

    serializer=fetchdataSerializers(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():

      serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

pagination.py

```
    class CustomPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):

      default_limit = 1000
      max_limit = 1000000
      min_limit = 1
      min_offset = 0
      max_offset = 1000000

       def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):

         limit = request.query_params.get('limit')
         offset = request.query_params.get('offset')

         if limit:

            limit = int(limit)

            if limit > self.max_limit:

              raise serializers.ValidationError({"limit" : ["Limit should be less 
              than or equal to {0}".format(self.max_limit)]})

            elif limit < self.min_limit:

              raise serializers.ValidationError({"limit" : ["Limit should be greater 
              than or equal to {0}".format(self.min_limit)]})

         if offset:

           offset = int(offset)

           if offset > self.max_offset:

             raise serializers.ValidationError({"offset" : ["Offset should be less 
             than or equal to {0}".format(self.max_offset)]})

          elif offset < self.min_offset:

            raise serializers.ValidationError({"offset" : ["Offset should be greater 
            than or equal to {0}".format(self.min_offset)]})

         return super(self.__class__, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, 
         view)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
# 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 100
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another custom limitOffset pagination. I like only passing the last part of the url to frontend.The page_size and offset can also be controlled by client

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from rest_framework.utils.urls import replace_query_param

def divide_numbers(a, b):
    if a % b:
        return (a // b) + 1
    return a // b


class StandardResultsSetPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 6
    limit_query_param = "page_size"
    offset_query_param = "offset"
    max_limit = 50



def get_next_link(self):
    if self.offset + self.limit >= self.count:  # type: ignore
           return None
    offset = self.offset + self.limit  # type: ignore
    return replace_query_param(url="", key=self.offset_query_param, val=offset)

def get_previous_link(self):
    if self.offset <= 0:
        return None

    url = replace_query_param(url="", key=self.limit_query_param, val=self.limit)

    if self.offset - self.limit <= 0:  # type: ignore
        return None

    offset = self.offset - self.limit  # type: ignore
    return replace_query_param(url="", key=self.offset_query_param, val=offset)


def get_pages(self):
    if self.limit:
        current = divide_numbers(self.offset, self.limit) + 1
        final = divide_numbers(
            self.count - self.offset, self.limit
        ) + divide_numbers(self.offset, self.limit)

        final = max(final, 1)
    else:
        current = 1
        final = 1

    if current > final:
        current = final

    return (current, final)


def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response(
        OrderedDict(
            [
                ("count", self.count),
                ("next", self.get_next_link()),
                ("current", self.get_pages()[0]),
                ("pages", self.get_pages()[1]),
                ("page_size", self.limit),
                ("previous", self.get_previous_link()),
                ("results", data),
            ]
        )
    )
```

sample response. Achieved by overriding rest framework response to format data in a certain standard and custom response codes

```
{
  "code": 2020,
  "msg": "Success",
  "data": {
    "count": 15,
    "current": 2,
    "pages": 3,
    "page_size": 6,
    "next": "?offset=12",
    "prev": null,
    "results": []
  }
}
```